# making an action to fire when navigating through the app

Tags: react-native, navigation

I made a navigation using `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator`
and I have a component thats being rendered when I switch to the screen using this navigation,
I want to make the navigation to fire a function everytime I enter the screen using this navigation,
something of a useEffect,
I tried doing useEffect with an empty array [], but it doesn't work, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the useFocusEffect hook which is similar to useEffect but it runs every time you navigate to a screen. But use effect will run only the first time.
You can see the sample code in the docs

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/